# Read from a text file into list then write cgi form response into that same file

Tags: python, html, list, cgi

I asked a question similar to this but I believe I made it too confusing to tell what I wanted.

I have a cgi script that i want the user to type in a keyword in.  There is a file keywords.txt that contains keywords.  The program will open that file and make it into a list.  Then, it should check to user if the keyword the user just entered is in that list.  If it is, it will take it to another cgi script, if it is not, it will write it to the file and take it to a different cgi script.

I am having trouble figuring out what variable to use in my IF statement to check if the user-inputed keyword is in the list.  Here is what I have so far, like I said my main problem if figuring out how to check if it is in the list and then adding it to the text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
keyword = form.getvalue('keyword')



print 'Content-type: text/html\r\n\r'
print '<html>'
print '<h1>Please enter a keyword of your choice</h1>'
print '<form action="results.cgi" method="post">'
print 'Keyword: <input type="text" name="keyword">  <br />'
print '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />'
print '</form>'
print '</html>'

keylist = []
f = open('keywords.txt', 'rw')
for each in f.readlines():
    keylist.append(each)

if keyword in keylist:
    print 'Location: %s' % #URL to second cgi script

else:
    f.write(keyword)
    f.close()
    print 'Location: %s' % #URL to 3rd cgi script
```

Comment: Everything seems right.. `if keyword in keylist`  is a perfect condition. What problem do you face?

Comment: you are closing the file only if the keyword is not in the keylist. use `with open('keywords.txt', 'rw') as f:` instead

Comment: The problem is the variable keyword isnt correct.  I need it to be what the user enters which I thought was keyword but it isnt.  The exact error I'm getting is: TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not None

Comment: does keywords.txt contain 1 keyword on each line ?

Comment: Yes, I want it to contain 1 keyword on each line.  Right now it is empty because I am trying to figure out how to write the keywords to it